# Merging 2 Python callables into a single callable

Tags: python

I have 2 Python callable objects (i.e. 2 function pointers). What's the cleanest way for me to merge these 2 into another callable?

Example:

```
a = lambda: 1
b = lambda: 2
```

I want to merge these 2 into `c` where `c()` will call both `a()` and `b()`.

EDIT:
To clarify, I want to keep `c` around and eventually call it later (which should call `a()` and `b()`.

Comment: depends on what they are doing. Can you please provide a more meaningful example to help you better ?

Answer (score 2):

Just put both of them in a tuple:

```
a = lambda: 1
b = lambda: 2
c = lambda: (a(), b())
```

---

```
>>> c()
(1, 2)
>>>
```

Comment: Added a clarification, I want to call `c` later eventually and have it call both `a` and `b`.